# Are there any desktop reminders for Linux that display pop-up notifications?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, notifications, popups, reminder

Are there any desktop reminders for Linux that display pop-up notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alarm Clock](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/)